# Adding new Basemap to Arcgis map using React

Tags: reactjs, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

In the [Arcgis](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.basemaps-amd.html) developer webpage, there is an article on how to add a new custom `baseMap` with custom `API url`. Which looks like this:

```
require([
    "esri/basemaps",
    "esri/map",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function (esriBasemaps, Map){
    esriBasemaps.delorme = {
      baseMapLayers: [{url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/DeLorme_World_Base_Map/MapServer"}
      ],
      thumbnailUrl: "https://www.example.com/images/thumbnail_2014-11-25_61051.png",
      title: "Delorme"
    };

    var map = new Map("ui-map", {
      basemap: "delorme",
      center: [-111.879655861, 40.571338776], // long, lat
      zoom: 13,
      sliderStyle: "small"
    });
});
```

Now I dont reallt understand how to do the same using [react-arcgis](https://github.com/Esri/react-arcgis). It seems that there is no built method in `react-arcgis` to use ``` custom API url`` as ``` BaseMap`but is there an option to do something similar in`React` ?

```
this.props.map.basemap = 'streets-relief-vector';
```

Instead of using the built in basemap strings.

Created also a simple [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-keller-hy6my?file=/src/App.js) to test this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **basemap** like this

`<Map mapProperties={{ basemap: "streets-relief-vector" }}>`

Comment: But I have a custom URL that I want to set my basemap from.